# Fixing laminate stair nose molding?

Tags: stairs, laminate

One of the stair nose came off and I’m trying to figure out the best way to put it back. There are tiny nails through the stair nose, and they all shifted. I think about removing them and applying some glue, but what is the best glue for the stairs? Any other ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would remove the whole thing first, to see if the wood is warped. This determines which strength you'll need to reapply it. If it's warped, you may need to use a mechanical binding method, i.e. screws.

Comment: Is it just the nosing that came up or the entire tread? Looks like the whole tread is lifting. If that's the case, it may be worthwhile pulling the whole tread up, cleaning out underneath it (removing any bent nails, construction debris, etc), and resetting the whole thing.

Comment: Only nosing. It's a little bit not even "by design"

Answer (score 1):

Remove the pins/nails, etc. and apply construction adhesive. Tape the molding securely in place overnight until it dries. If you have a brad nailer you could use that instead of tape.

I'm not sure what all that is "inside" the stair... but you'll want to clean that out and the adhesive should allow you to fill the void a little bit.